# Where are Office macros stored?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to extract Office macros from a malicious .docx file, but I don't want to open the file, even with macros disabled. I'm looking to read the macro from a supplied file and output it to text.

I've seen the OLETools program, but I can't find how they are getting the macros from the file.

Any help on where the macros are located in the file structure would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make the file a zip file, you can pull out the vbAProject.bin section...

1)  Make a copy of your file

2)  Rename your copied file extension to .zip

3)  Go into the .zip file

4)  Go into xl folder

5)  Find vbaProject.bin

You can actual create a separate workbook, do the zip thing, and paste in the .bin file... after that, change the extension back to the desired extension and open it.

Similar thing can be done for Word.